# Decrement/Increment Date Angular 7

Tags: angular7

How can decrement the current day or increment in Angular 7 using this property "Date.now()" that is in Documentation ?

Component

```
today: number = Date.now()
```

HTML

```
<td>{{ today | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy '}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let date= new Date();
let diff = 1; //1 to increment and -1 to decrement
date.setDate(today.getDate() + diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

**100 working solution**

```
   today=new Date();
  constructor(
  ) {
    console.log('11... today date',this.today);
    var tom=this.today.setDate(this.today.getDate()+3);
    var tomformatted=formatDate(tom, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss',
    'en-US');
    console.log('11... tommorow formatted date',tomformatted);
   
  }
```

**Console Logs**
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to import formatDate  i.e.  import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';